# Menu dropping down when it shouldn't be?

Tags: html, css

The top navigation of this page is what I'm working on: http://www.envisionforce.com/newsletter/

For some reason there's a drop down menu showing when you hover over the navigation which I need to remove from this page.

This is the code used for the top navigation:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="main_menu" class="nav"><li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-22"><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com">HOME</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1966" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1966"><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com/build">SERVICES</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2160"><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com/seo-resellers/">RESELLERS</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2159"><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com/affiliate-program/">AFFILIATES</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com/contact-us/">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

I'd really like to stay away from editing the CSS file itself.  Is there any way I can fix this in just the above code with inline CSS?  If not possible, the solution to fixing it in the CSS file would be very welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove following properties from your css

```
.nav li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.nav li a 
{
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(22, 45, 61);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(35, 56, 71);
}
```

**Second option :**

You can just write this css on your page under `<style>` tag

```
.nav li a:hover
{
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.nav li a 
{
  border:none;
}
```

This will overwrite your external css property and it will remove that submenu on hover.

Comment: What line are you seeing that on?  I'm not even seeing the word `scroll` in my CSS file - that's what I was originally looking for when I started working on this actually.

Comment: actually it is at `1661` line number and it is written as `#menu_wrapper .nav ul li a.hover,#menu_wrapper .nav ul li a:hover,#menu_wrapper div .nav li a.hover,#menu_wrapper div .nav li a:hover {
    background: #000;
}` this property is looking in browser as I shown in my answer so remove it from here or can use my second option

Comment: The first option somewhat works because it removes the filled in color but you can still see where it's dropping down because of borders around the dropdown.  I just tried the second option which looks like it fits my situation better, but it doesn't appear to be working at all :/

Comment: Ohh yes it is because we have set `left` and `right` `border` for submenu. So you can remove it either remove `.nav li a 
{
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(22, 45, 61);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(35, 56, 71);
}` from CSS or write on your page as .nav li a{ border:none;}. I have updated my second option too.

Comment: Just tried the second option and nothing seems to have changed on my end... Is it working properly when you go to the page?

Comment: Yes dude it is working as we want that's why I put this solution here :)

Comment: Ok... I've cleared my cache and use a browser that I've never viewed that page in but I'm still seeing the dropdown...

Comment: btw do one more thing. delete `.nav li a` css class from your CSS file at line number `1638`

Comment: When I do that it completely messes up the navigation on that page...  Like there's no spacing or borders

Comment: Got it fixed, I just created a new CSS file and used your first method ;)  Thanks!

Comment: btw I got one more thing in your css ie. `a:hover {
    min-height: 400px;` just remove it and I think your existing CSS will work as well